# IFTTT Toggle Button Widget

Tags: automation, ifttt

I would like to create a button widget in [IFTTT](https://ifttt.com/) for toggling my Bluetooth On and Off with the same button.

However, it is only possible to select either 'Turn on Bluetooth' or 'Turn off Bluetooth' as action for the button press (or any other trigger, for that matter), which means I would end up with two buttons. But I would like to have only one button that turns Off Bluetooth if its On and vice versa.

If this is not possible with IFTTT, I'm open for other suggestions to implement this.

Comment: Use [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid). Trigger; Empty trigger; Action: Bluetooth Configure > toggle Bluetooth. Create a short cut to this macro by dragging the Macrodroid  shortcuts widget to home screen and assign it to this macro which you named and saved. I was not sure if you meant *other suggestions* to include other apps or only IFTTT hence the comment and not an answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well, I'd like to do it with IFTTT if possible because I already use it and I don't want to install another app just for this function. But if it turns out that it's not possible at all, I might go to a different app altogether so solutions with other apps are welcome.